# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, google-chrome, headless, selenium

**IT IS IN PATH**

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable:/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver:/usr/lib/chromium-browser/
```

Edit

I had an error in my path. `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver` should have been `/usr/lib/chromium-browser`

Comment: So where is `chromedriver` located? Update your question with a `ls -l` command.